# Как убрать плавающую точку в float

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка, которая передает вложенную в нее цифру, к примеру "7" в float переменную activity. После я запускаю эту переменную в TextView, и мне, разумеется мне выдает "7.0"... Как убрать эту точку и ноль если после точки нет других дробных чисел?

Answer (score -1):

Можно преобразовать в строку, разделить её по точке, сравнить число после точки с нулём и преобразовать целую часть в `int`:

```
            int result;
            float f = 7.0f;
            String[] strings = String.valueOf(f).split(".");
            if (strings[1].equals("0")){
               result = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
            }
```

Comment: @AleksandrBarakin что случилось? Никто кроме меня не дал ни ответ ни хотя бы комментарий, а на мой единственый ответ поставили дизлайк. Если кому-то не нравится чьё-то решение, то пусть тогда они предложат лучшее решение, вместо того, чтобы дизлайкать, не так ли?

Comment: @aepot посмотрите этот ответ